# One-dimensional Integral

Tags: integration, gamma-function

I have seen an integral \begin{equation}\frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{\frac{n_z}{2}}} \int_{\varepsilon_{v}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}|| \boldsymbol{v} \|^{2}} \,\mathrm{d}v\,,\end{equation} where $\mathcal{E}_{v}:=\left\{v:\|v\|^{2} \leq r^{2}\right\}.$

It results in the integration $$I=\frac{1}{2^{n_{z} / 2} \Gamma\left(n_{z} / 2\right)} \int_{0}^{r^{2}} \chi^{\frac{n_{z}}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{\chi}{2}} d \chi$$

I am wondering why the result of the first integral is not the same as $\int e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$, which leads to $\sqrt{2}\Gamma{(\frac{1}{2})}$. And how should I evaluate the integral over $0$ to $r^2$ in the second equation.

Any hints are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How is it connected with the control-theory tag?

Comment: I have read this integral from several papers for closed-loop stochastic dynamic process optimization. The result is also directly applied in stochastic MPC, therefore I tagged it with 'control theory' with the hope that people from control background could explain this. I am sorry if this tag is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your integral in terms of $\chi$, change variables to $y = \chi / 2$. This removes the factor of $1/2$ in the exponential and then you'll be able to see that it's an incomplete gamma function integral.

The reason that the integral is different from
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$  is that your original integral is over an n-dimensional space. Your integral is spherically symmetric, so to get to your final form you need to first change coordinates to spherical polars. The factor of $\chi^{\frac{n_{z}}{2}-1}$ comes from the volume element in spherical polars, and the $\Gamma\left(n_{z} / 2\right)$ in the answer comes from the integration over the angular coordinates, it's related to the volume of the n-ball.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This is exactly the solution I'm looking for. Have a good day :).